# VBA: RubberDuck add-in: @VariableDescription how it works?

Tags: vba, microsoft-office

I use [RubberDuck add-in](https://rubberduckvba.com) (beside other) to annotate my VBA code using [`@Description`](https://rubberduckvba.wordpress.com/2019/12/14/rubberduck-annotations/#highlighter_290882:%7E:text=project.-,Member%20Annotations,End%20Sub) (for Subs, Function, Properties...) and want to use [`@VariableDescription`](https://rubberduckvba.com/Annotations/Details/VariableDescription) for variables. But unlike [`@Description`](https://rubberduckvba.com/Features/FeatureItem/Description) used form members I can't see these variable descriptions in Code Explorer.

There is the only documentation I found about: [`@VariableDescription`](https://rubberduckvba.com/Annotations/Details/VariableDescription). I understand that `@VariableDescritption` is for variables what `@Description` is for other members - it has to be shown in the [Code Explorer](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/wiki/Code-Explorer) too.

What I'm missing? How is it supposed to work?

PS: I decided to post it to Super User instead of Stack Overflow, because this is tool-related problem. If you consider my decision as wrong, please move it to proper section and accept my apologies.

Comment: FYI there's a [tag:rubberduck] tag on SO that's perfectly fine too (not familiar enough with SU posting guidelines to tell if the post should be moved or not though)

Comment: Interesting, SU tells me [there is no rubberduck tag](https://ibb.co/Q8Z80cr)...

Comment: @MathieuGuindon Could be useful to add this tag here and also add link to thetag on RubberDuck homepage. (At fist I sought support/forum link there, but found nothing.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#### TL;DR:

Variable descriptions work for module variables, but they only appear in the *Object Browser* - making variable descriptions appear in both Rubberduck's *command bar* and *Code Explorer* toolwindow would have to be implemented for a future release.

---

In a dream world, there would only have been a `@Description` annotation, usable for everything that can take a description. However, correctly scoping annotations and associating them to their annotated "target" proved to be a challenge in a number of edge cases, most particularly with properly tagging a module's first member:

```vb
Option Explicit
'@Description "does this belong to the module or the 1st member?
Public Sub DoSomething()
End Sub
```

In order to disambiguate, the module-level annotation describing the module itself became `@ModuleDescription`, and the module-level annotation describing module-level variables became `@VariableDescription`.

Annotation comments don't do anything by themselves, but once Rubberduck has parsed the project it is able to compare the annotation comments to the module's hidden `VB_Attribute` values, and *Code Inspections* flag desynchronized attributes/annotations under the *Rubberduck Opportunities* category.

Once synchronized, the description string appears in the VBE's *Object Browser* (<kbd>F2</kbd>):

[image: Object Browser showing the description text]

Now, Rubberduck's *Code Explorer* also displays these descriptions:

[image: Code Explorer showing module description]

...but it appears *variable* descriptions don't show up:

[image: Code Explorer not showing variable description]

Descriptions should also appear in Rubberduck's command bar:

[image: command bar showing module description]

The fact that it's not showing up for a module variable...

[image: command bar not showing variable description]

...tells me that this was an oversight and it needs to be fixed!

This should be a relatively easy fix that can ship with the next release :)

EDIT: the bug is being fixed in [this pull request](https://github.com/rubberduck-vba/Rubberduck/pull/5701).

Comment: And merged - once the build completes on [next], download the latest pre-release version to get the fix.